# Upload image byte[] with POST

Tags: java, android

How to send Image or Video with post request with lot off other parameters with post request ? I have image and video in byte[] format and I am trying like

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            http.setURI(URI.create(url));
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                  ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(a.getData(),
                      a.getQuestionId() + ".jpg");
                  reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));            
                  reqEntity.addPart("data", bab);
 http.setEntity(reqEntity);
              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(http);
```

it pass through code but it doesn't upload anything ( bab !=null ). Does anybody have any idea what is wrong, I cannot provide more info, other team is at ws ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look something more like this:

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(a.getData(), a.getQuestionId() + ".jpg");
reqEntity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));            
reqEntity.addPart("data", bab);

HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
postMethod.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient():
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
```

Comment: @ Percepion What is a difference ?

Comment: @Damir - the difference would depend on what you defined `http` in your code to be.